# SwiftUI: header image that expands

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, scrollview

I have a `Scrollview` inside a `NavigationStack` and want a sticky image on top. When scrolling down, the image should expand, it should also bleed into the navigation bar.

I've got it working with `GeometryReader`, but it seems to be causing many re-renders and it's very noticeable that it doesn't run great.

```
struct TestView: View {
    let coordinateSpaceName = "navstack"
    @State var size: CGRect = .zero

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                Text("y: \(size.minY), height: \(size.height)")
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                    .background(
                        Image(systemName: "star")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .opacity(0.2)
                            .frame(height: max(0, size.minY + size.height))
                            // ^ set background size to parent height + distance to top
                            .offset(x: 0, y: -(size.minY / 2))
                            // ^ move up
                            
                    )
                    .overlay( // read own size and distance to top
                        GeometryReader { proxy in
                            let offset = proxy.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName)).minY
                            Color.clear
                                .preference(key: StickyHeaderPreferenceKey.self, value: CGRect(
                                    x: 0,
                                    y: offset,
                                    width: 0,
                                    height: proxy.size.height
                                ))
                        })
                    .onPreferenceChange(StickyHeaderPreferenceKey.self) { value in
                        size = value // save new values
                    }
                Color.gray.frame(height: 1000)
                    .opacity(0.3)

            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: coordinateSpaceName)
    }
}
```

```
struct StickyHeaderPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGRect = CGRect()
    static func reduce(value: inout CGRect, nextValue: () -> CGRect) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

It looks/should look like this (apart from the "getting smaller when swiping up" part):

[Expanding header image](https://i.imgur.com/qZroTKd.mp4)

I noticed that the `.background` of the first item in the `NavigationStack` is going under the navigation bar just as I want it, I couldn't get it to work with a `ScrollView` or `List` though:

```
NavigationStack {
    VStack (spacing: 0) {
        Text("The background of this should bleed into the navigation bar, while being scrollable")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .frame(height: 200)
            .background(
                Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                    .opacity(0.2)
            )
        ScrollView {
            Color.gray.frame(height: 1000)
        }
    }
    .navigationTitle("Navigation Title")
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
}
```

Is there a simpler solution for this? Or any obvious issues I'm having here?

Comment: `.toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)`? Is that what you are looking for? "it seems to be causing many re-renders and it's very noticeable" What exactly did you notice? I didn't notice many re-renders.

Comment: A visual example of what you're trying to achieve might help the community members to better understand the question and provide you with some useful information.

Comment: @Mev Is the video not working for you? It basically looks like it should (also the example should work the way it is), the question I'm having is if there's a more straightforward/better way to achieve the same behaviour.

Comment: @Sweeper It basically looks like it should, the navigationbar should be visible (what I meant is if scrolled to the top the background should not be blurred by a material, but that's already the case). The re-reders might be coming from another problem and this is just surfacing it. I'm using SwiftData, the image is the background for the parent detail and below is a list with child elements. It seems to be reloading the child elements every time, but again, probably a different problem. I just wanted to know if there's a better way to achieve this particular one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If I understand your requirements correctly:*

- Inside the `NavigationStack`, the parent container is either a `ScrollView` or a `List`. In other words, the parent container supports scrolling.
- The background behind the container should extend to the top of the screen, that is, into the safe area.
- When the scrollable container is pulled down, the background should appear pinned to both the top of the screen and the bottom of the content, so it should grow to fill the extra height.
- When the scrollable container is scrolled up, the background should stay at its original size and move with the scrolled content.

You actually have this working with the first block of code you provided, except that the size of the background also shrinks when scrolling up. However, there is no `VStack` inside the `ScrollView` to define the layout of the content.

In the last block of code that you provided (where you say it is not working), you have added a `VStack` as the top-level container, but of course it is not scrollable. If I understand correctly, the `Text` is a placeholder for the scrollable container you want to have. However, it is confusing to see the `Text` inside the `VStack` and followed by a `ScrollView`. I assume this is not the actual arrangement you want to have.

**Down to business**

I think that all you need to do is put the `VStack` inside the `ScrollView` and attach the background to this. This way, the background scrolls with the content.

To stop it shrinking, you need to know the minimum height to constrain it to. This can be found by putting a `GeometryReader` around the background.

I found it was also necessary to hide the background behind the navigation bar, otherwise it adds a `Material` effect as soon as the content scrolls up behind it.

> Is there a simpler solution for this?

I would also use a `GeometryReader` in the background to measure the position of the scrolled content, but it can be done without using a `PreferenceKey`. The global coordinate space can be used too, there is no need to name the coordinate space of the `ScrollView`.

You are using a `CGRect` as the state variable. It would probably be sufficient to use a `CGFloat` that just stores `maxY`. But I left it as `CGRect`, in case I've misunderstood the requirements and you want to read other values from the frame info.

This works in the way described in the points above:

```swift
struct NewTestView: View {

    @State private var size: CGRect = .zero

    private var positionDetector: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let frame = proxy.frame(in: .global)
            Color.clear
                // pre iOS 17: .onChange(of: frame) { newVal in
                .onChange(of: frame) { oldVal, newVal in
                    size = newVal
                }
        }
    }

    private var star: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let h = proxy.size.height
            let minY = proxy.frame(in: .global).minY
            Image(systemName: "star")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .opacity(0.2)
                .frame(height: max(h, size.maxY))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .offset(y: min(0, -minY))
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Text("y: \(size.minY), height: \(size.height)")
                        .frame(height: 200)
                        .frame(minWidth: 300)
                        .border(.gray)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                }
                .background { positionDetector }
                .background { star }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation Title")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
            .toolbarBackground(.hidden, for: .navigationBar)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Aniimation]

Comment: Answer revised again

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, thanks :)
I'm using a `List` and for some reason the `size.maxY` didn't update without the `PreferenceKey` (I also moved the entire logic and `@State` directly onto the `VStack` element). I'm still having one issue that I couldn't fix: the view is in a `.sheet` and when swiping it down, the image should stay at the top of the sheet, currently it moves up beyond the sheet top. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @fer0n Pleased to hear that it was worth it in the end! I'm not sure what the issue is with the sheet, surely you don't have a `NavigationStack` inside the sheet? If the image is moving up when it shouldn't be then it sounds like it might be applying a negative y-offset, so you could try `max(0, offset)` to stop it going negative. Otherwise, suggest addressing in a new question with a reproducible example. Ps, if the answer helped, you are welcome to accept it or give it an upvote ;)